# RangeError: invalid time value — solve without resolving as string?

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, datetime, frontend

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

interface DatePickerProps {
    value?: Date;
    onChange?: (value: Date) => void;
    disabled?: boolean;
}
    
export const DatePicker = (props: DatePickerProps) => {
    const { onChange, disabled, value } = props
    const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = React.useState<Date | undefined>(value);

    const handleDateChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const newDate = new Date(event.target.value);
        setSelectedDate(newDate);
        onChange && onChange(newDate);
    };
  
    return (
        <DatePickerWrapper disabled={disabled}>
            <Input
                type="date"
                value={selectedDate?.toISOString().slice(0, 10)}
                onChange={handleDateChange}
                disabled={disabled}
                min={new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)}
            />
        </DatePickerWrapper>
    );
};
```

Here's my code for a date picker ... is there any way to fix this without resolving as a string? I want `selectedDate` to remain as type `Date`.

.ToISOString() seems to be the most common solution but it's converting to type string, and I can't reassign selectedDate as a Date.

Does someone know if there's any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If your `<Input>` component wraps a standard HTML `<input>`, then unfortunately there is no way to set the `value` and get the `event.target.value` directly as `Date`, they will always be `string` with format `yyyy-mm-dd`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#value

> A string representing a date in YYYY-MM-DD format, or empty

---

While there exist `valueAsNumber` (taking a timestamp) and directly `valueAsDate` JS properties ([IDL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#technical_summary)), they do not have equivalent HTML attributes, hence they are not supported by React as-is unfortunately (see e.g. [fb/react#11369](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11369))